# Difference between ports and us.archive

Tags: apt, official-repositories, apt-mirror

What is the difference between `ports.ubuntu.com`  and `us.archive.ubuntu.com`? I ask because I already have an apt-mirror for `us.archive.ubuntu.com` and don't want to add `ports.ubuntu.com` if it is not necessary.

Does `us.archive.ubuntu.com` not have armhf packages?

Comment: No, nor does it have PPC packages. The one you have is Intel's x86 only, while ports has the non-x86.

Comment: Make sense. I am a bit new to these architectures, but if I want to mirror the ppa `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/armhf`, how do I add that to my `sources.list`?

Comment: You've to use `http://ports.ubuntu.com/`

Comment: I use: "deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ lunar main restricted universe multiverse" in  sources.list, but anyway, redirect is to: "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lunar/main/binary-armhf/Packages"